# What does a variable with an @ symbol mean in an Ant build.xml?

Tags: ant

Can anyone tell me what an @ symbol before a variable means in ant build.xml file?

```
<subant target="@{target}">
```

Comment: It means you are in a macro definition.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no variables in (core) ant, but properties and attributes.
@{foo} is the syntax for accessing the value of a macrodef attribute inside a macrodef, i.e. :

```
<project name="tryme">
 <macrodef name="whatever">
  <attribute name="foo" default="bar"/>
   <sequential>
    <echo>foo =>  @{foo}</echo>
   </sequential>
 </macrodef>

 <!-- testing 1, foo attribute not set, will use default value -->
 <whatever/>

 <!-- testing 2,  set attribute foo to 'baz'-->
 <whatever foo="baz"/>
</project>
```

output :

```
 [echo] foo =>  bar
 [echo] foo =>  baz
```

See [Ant manual macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)
Whereas ${foo} is the syntax for accessing the value of a property :

```
<project name="demo">
 <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
 <echo>$${foo} => ${foo}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${foo} => bar
```

See [Ant manual property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)

Comment: Strike ;-) Cheers || Slàinte mhath